# How to get the total of all odd numbers from a range that are less than 10?

Tags: excel

I have a list, and I want to get the total of all odd numbers from the list that are less than 10.
[Below is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lm40.png)

Comment: Please post your data as markdown sample data, then include your desired result included your own attempt. Hint: `SUMPRODUCT()`.

Comment: Use even() or odd() then sumproduct().

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following formula to sum the odd numbers, just substitute your ranges accordingly.

`=Sumproduct( --(Mod([Your Range],2)=1),--([Your Range]<10), [Your Range])`

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISODD(--([Your Range]))),--([Your Range]<10),[Your Range])`

Comment: You forgot the less than 10 part.

Comment: @ScottCraner, Thanks for the feedback, added that part to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. @Mark S. and @ Scott Craner.